# How to remove all simultaneous connections from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a web app with firebase Realtime database with free plan having 100 simultaneous connection limit. I have logged in with only one google account. But it is showing 3 simultaneous connections every time. Yes, sometimes it drops to 2 connections but not below 2. I can recall that few days ago I had signed in with 2 custom made email-password authentication. But now I have logged out from both of them and deleted the 2 accounts and I have also disabled email-password authentication method. Still it is showing 3 simultaneous connection. Reminding you currently I am logged in with only 1 google account still it is showing 3 simultaneous connections.

**How to solve this problem?**

OR

**Tell me some way to manually remove all simultaneous connection from firebase Realtime Database**, so that I can retry by logging in with different methods and debug that what is actually causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simultaneous connection is any client currently connected to your app, this is specifically any instances of your firebase that has connected with your project credentials regardless of a user logging in or not.

Per the documentation

> A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database.

I do believe that the counter is also delayed by an hour or two to reduce live update bandwidth and logging into your Firebase console itself also counts as a connection.

Comment: so, it means that I don't need to write any extra code for simultaneous connection for a user to get disconneted from a server. According to you as soon as user will close browser tab his simultaneous connection will not be counted. Am i right?

Comment: Correct, the limitation is specifically for development purposes only. not something you need to worry about as it's only currently connected applications.